# Navigation drawer selected item textColor by Custom Adapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, navigation-drawer, textcolor

May i know how to change the selected item's text color in navigation drawer.

The **android:textColor** for listview is not working after install appcompat_v7 22.1.1 
so i think i cannot change using selector drawable.

I manage to change the default color of drawer items by using custom adapter.

But this only manage to set the first item to green when initialized.

May i know how to change the color of selected items(onclick) to the color i want when item is selected.

Adapter:

```
public class NavigationDrawerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private int mSelectedItem;
    private final Context context;
    private String[] sections;

    public NavigationDrawerAdapter(Context context, int resource, String[] objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        sections = objects;
    }
    public int getSelectedItem() {
        return mSelectedItem;
    }
    public void setSelectedItem(int selectedItem) {
        mSelectedItem = selectedItem;
    }

    private String getMenuItemTitle(int position) {
        if (position >= 0 && position <= sections.length)
            return sections[position];
        return "Invalid section requested";
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //Get item TextView
        TextView view = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        view.setText(getMenuItemTitle(position));

        if (position == mSelectedItem) {
            view.setTextColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
        } else {
            view.setTextColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.white));        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

Navigation drawer:

```
mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new NavigationDrawerAdapter(
                getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
                new String[]{
                        getString(R.string.title_home),
                        getString(R.string.title_stamp),
                        getString(R.string.title_scanner),
                        getString(R.string.title_setting),}) {

        });
        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
        return mDrawerListView;
..
...
private void selectItem(int position) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;

        if (mDrawerListView != null) {
            mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had found the solution.

Since i have extend the adapter.
I'm just need to call and change the selected Item by position when item clicked to make changes.

ListDrawer onItemClickListener:

```
 mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectItem(position);

                myadapter.setSelectedItem(position);

            }
```

And From the custom adapter:

```
public void setSelectedItem(int selectedItem) {
        mSelectedItem = selectedItem;
    }

    private String getMenuItemTitle(int position) {
        if (position >= 0 && position <= sections.length)
            return sections[position];
        return "Invalid section requested";
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //Get item TextView
      TextView view = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        view.setText(getMenuItemTitle(position));

        if (position == mSelectedItem) {
            view.setTextColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
        } else {
            view.setTextColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.normal));
        }

        return view;
    }
```

*adapter class is on question.

source : [samsaodev.com](https://blog.samsaodev.com/how-to-customise-the-text-appearance-of-a-selected-section-in-a-navigation-drawer/)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of parsing all the items of your Navigation Drawer ,simply create a Color State List Resource [See documentation here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html)

**drawer_text_selector.xml** in your **res/color** folder

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item 
     android:state_activated="false"
     android:color="@color/drawer_text_normal"/>
   <item
     android:state_pressed="true"
     android:color="@color/drawer_text_pressed"/>
   <item
     android:state_activated="true"
     android:color="@color/drawer_text_pressed"/>
</selector>
```

Then in your drawer list item set the textColor of your TextView to :

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/drawerText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/drawer_text_selector" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Do something after some time
            for (int i = 0; i < recyclerViewDrawer1.getChildCount(); i++) {
                ImageView imageViewDrawerItemIcon = (ImageView) recyclerViewDrawer1
                        .getChildAt(i).findViewById(
                                R.id.imageViewDrawerItemIcon);
                TextView textViewDrawerItemTitle = (TextView) recyclerViewDrawer1
                        .getChildAt(i).findViewById(
                                R.id.textViewDrawerItemTitle);
                LinearLayout linearLayoutItem = (LinearLayout) recyclerViewDrawer1
                        .getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutItem);
                if (i == 0) {
                    imageViewDrawerItemIcon.setColorFilter(colorPrimary);

                    textViewDrawerItemTitle.setTextColor(colorPrimary);
                    linearLayoutItem
                            .setBackgroundColor(colorControlHighlight);
                } else {
                    imageViewDrawerItemIcon
                            .setColorFilter(textColorPrimary);

                    textViewDrawerItemTitle.setTextColor(textColorPrimary);
                    linearLayoutItem.setBackgroundColor(colorBackground);
                }
            }
        }
    }, 250);
```